# Como puedo guardar una Uri Component en un archivo plano y luego recuperarla otravez tipo Uri component

Tags: kotlin

Estoy intentando esto.

```
val str= imgUri.toString()//aqui convierto el archivo de uri component a un tipo String

str.toUri()// aqui regreso la cadena a Uri.

dataSet.add(datacomida(str1,str))// agrego a un array tipo mutablelist<datacomida>=arrayListof()
str // es de tipo Uri supuestamente ya que la converti.
str1// es de tipo String
```

la falla es que al cargar el dataset al recyclerview este no me carga y revienta la aplicacion sin mostrar una leyenda.
Existe alguna otra forma de hacer mejor lo que busco en mi pregunta o que estoy haciendo mal.?